# Schema generator for my customers to create their own business schema

Tags: json, schema, generator

I'm trying to reinvent the wheel a little bit, but I want my clients to be able to generate their own schema json on my website. I have got to the point where I am almost there, but rather than tell them to add  //<script type="application/ld+json">//  before the code that is output, I want it pre-populated in the output box.

I can write some code but not enough to now where to go from here. Also for open days and time. I can't find how to add each individual day with open and close time.

Cheers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Generate your Local Business JSON Schema</title>
<p>Fill in details below</p>
<p>then copy and paste into your website. Once schema markup has been added to your website, use <a href="https://validator.schema.org/"> the Schema  Testing Tool as a final step to ensure proper schema implementation.</a></p>

</head>
<body>
  <h2>Your Own Schema Generator</h2>

  <form id="schemaForm">
    <label for="businessType">Business Type:</label>
    <input type="text" id="businessType" name="businessType"><br><br>

    <label for="businessName">Business Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="businessName" name="businessName"><br><br>

    <label for="website">Website:</label>
    <input type="text" id="website" name="website"><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"><br><br>

    <label for="streetAddress">Street Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="streetAddress" name="streetAddress"><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br><br>

    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br><br>

    <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"><br><br>

    <label for="countryCode">Country Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="countryCode" name="countryCode"><br><br>

    <label for="openDays">Open Days (Monday to Sunday):</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="openDays" name="openDays"><br><br>

    <button type="submit">Generate Schema</button>
  </form>

  <div id="output">
    <h2>Generated JSON Schema:</h2>
    <textarea id="schemaOutput" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("schemaForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      generateSchema();
    });

    function generateSchema() {
      var schema = {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "name": document.getElementById("businessName").value,
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": document.getElementById("streetAddress").value,
          "addressLocality": document.getElementById("city").value,
          "addressRegion": document.getElementById("state").value,
          "postalCode": document.getElementById("postcode").value,
          "addressCountry": document.getElementById("countryCode").value
        },
        "url": document.getElementById("website").value,
        "email": document.getElementById("email").value,
        "telephone": document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value,
        "openingHoursSpecification": {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": document.getElementById("openDays").value.split(","),
          "opens": "09:00",
          "closes": "18:00"
        }
      };

      var schemaOutput = document.getElementById("schemaOutput");
      schemaOutput.value = JSON.stringify(schema, null, 2);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried below but nothing was output

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Local Business JSON Schema Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Local Business JSON Schema Generator</h1>

    <form id="schemaForm">
        <label for="businessType">Business Type:</label>
        <input type="text" id="businessType" name="businessType"><br>

        <label for="businessName">Business Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="businessName" name="businessName"><br>

        <label for="website">Website:</label>
        <input type="text" id="website" name="website"><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>

        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"><br>

        <label for="streetAddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="streetAddress" name="streetAddress"><br>

        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>

        <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"><br>

        <label for="countryCode">Country Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="countryCode" name="countryCode"><br>

        <label for="openDays">Open Days:</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="monday" name="openDays" value="Monday">
        <label for="monday">Monday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="openDays" value="Tuesday">
        <label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" name="openDays" value="Wednesday">
        <label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" name="openDays" value="Thursday">
        <label for="thursday">Thursday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="friday" name="openDays" value="Friday">
        <label for="friday">Friday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="openDays" value="Saturday">
        <label for="saturday">Saturday</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" name="openDays" value="Sunday">
        <label for="sunday">Sunday</label><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Generate JSON Schema">
    </form>

    <pre id="schemaOutput"></pre>

    <script type="application/ld+json">
        function generateSchema(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData(event.target);

            var schema = {
                "@context": "https://schema.org",
                "@type": "LocalBusiness",
                "name": formData.get("businessName"),
                "url": formData.get("website"),
                "email": formData.get("email"),
                "telephone": formData.get("phoneNumber"),
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": formData.get("streetAddress"),
                    "addressLocality": formData.get("city"),
                    "addressRegion": formData.get("state"),
                    "postalCode": formData.get("postcode"),
                    "addressCountry": formData.get("countryCode")
                },
                "openingHoursSpecification": [
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("monday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("tuesday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("wednesday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("thursday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("friday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Saturday",
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("saturday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                        "dayOfWeek": [
                            "Sunday",
                            "Monday",
                            "Tuesday",
                            "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday",
                            "Friday",
                            "Saturday"
                        ],
                        "opens": "00:00",
                        "closes": formData.get("sunday") ? "23:59" : "00:00"
                    }
                ]
            };

            document.getElementById("schemaOutput").textContent = JSON.stringify(schema, null, 2);
        }

        document.getElementById("schemaForm").addEventListener("submit", generateSchema);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```